# How do you remove the filename 'index.php' on slim framework url endpoint?

Tags: php, rest, slim

the output:

```
localhost:8080/index.php/hello/world
```

should be:

```
localhost:8080/hello/world
```

I am using PHP Built-in Server, not Apache.

Comment: The same way you remove it for any router that uses the URI part of the URL

Comment: Did you read the [web servers section from the docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html) on their site?

Comment: Have you tried to start it with: `php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php`?

Comment: Okay the main catch here is that I named my file as main.php and not index.php while using php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php

Comment: Therefore to Slim PHP the default index filename is index.php.